# How Can I Have Two Numeric Inputs in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Below I have an R code that takes an input value from the numericInput object and stores it in an Excel spreadsheet. I am now trying to have two numericInput's, but I'm not sure how to do that. Below in the code, I tried to just duplicate the object as a last resort effort, but it gave me an error. (I'm not surprised) Any advice?

```
library(shiny)
library(xlsxjars)
library(rJava)
library(xlsx)

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput(inputId = "num", 
               label = "Choose a number",
               min = 0, max = 1000000, value = 1),
  actionButton(inputId = "submit", 
               label = "Submit"),
  numericInput(inputId = "num2", 
               label = "Choose a number2", min = 0, max = 1000000, value = 1),
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  options(java.parameters = "- Xmx1024m")
  wb <- loadWorkbook(file = "F:\\RProject-Rough\\DirectEffect.xlsx")
  sheet<-getSheets(wb)

  observeEvent(input$submit, {
          addDataFrame(c(input$num,input$num2), sheet$'Direct Effects',
          col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, startRow = 3,startColumn = 5)
          saveWorkbook(wb,"F:\\RProject-Rough\\DirectEffect.xlsx")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, after your second numericInput, there is a comma that does not belong there.

Secondly, `addDataFrame` takes a data.frame as an argument and not a vector.

The following works for me:

```
library(shiny)
library(xlsxjars)
library(rJava)
library(xlsx)

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput(inputId = "num", 
               label = "Choose a number",
               min = 0, max = 1000000, value = 1),
  actionButton(inputId = "submit", 
               label = "Submit"),
  numericInput(inputId = "num2", 
               label = "Choose a number2", min = 0, max = 1000000, value = 1)
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  options(java.parameters = "- Xmx1024m")
  wb <- loadWorkbook(file = "/PATH/TO/test.xlsx")
  sheet <- getSheets(wb)

  observeEvent(input$submit, {
    addDataFrame(data.frame(c(input$num,input$num2)), sheet$`Direct Effects`, 
    col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, startRow = 3, startColumn = 5)
    saveWorkbook(wb, "/PATH/TO/test.xlsx")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Oh thank you so much. Sorry about the silly mistakes.